# Usage of iteritems() in insertion a dict to sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

My "video_episodes" table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE "video_episodes" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "dizilink_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "video_dizilink" ("id"),
    "episodename" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "episodeurl" varchar(200) NOT NULL);
```

I'm trying to insert some values within a dict:

```
video_links = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO video_episodes(dizilink_id, episodename, episodeurl) VALUES (?,?,?)""", dizilink_id, video_links.iteritems(),)
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Without dizilink_id, I'm able to insert with iteritems() but I can't understand how it's possible with additional key(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with iteritems.

As the error message says, `executemany` (why are you using many, rather than simple `execute`?) takes two arguments, and you are passing three. The parameters to the SQL statement are a single parameter, so need to be wrapped in a tuple.

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO video_episodes(dizilink_id, episodename, episodeurl) VALUES (?,?,?)""", (dizilink_id, video_links.iteritems()))
```

**Edit after comment** OK, I think I understand what you are trying to do now. You want to insert multiple values of (episodename, episodeurl) for the *same* value of dizilink_id.

You can't do that with executemany. You'll need to run multiple commands. Something like this:

```
for name, url in video_links.iteritems():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO video_episodes(dizilink_id, episodename, episodeurl) "
                   " VALUES (?,?,?)", (dizilink_id, name, url))
```

Comment: With the code you've provided, it gives a different error:

sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 2 supplied.

Comment: You saved my day! :) But why can't we do this with executemany? Is "dizilink_id" the only reason for using your "for loop"?

Comment: Yes, because there's no concept of keeping one item the same while you're iterating through another. There would be ways of making it work, but this is probably simpler.